# Google Analytics: How to integrate into Android application?

Tags: android, sdk, google-analytics

How do I integrate Google analytic's into my simple Android Application?

I've seen a guide [here,](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) but I cannot find a download link for the SDK.

Any tutorials would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Google Play Services 
[Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)
Just follow the instructions for your IDE

Comment: Thanks, so i do not need the Google analytics SDK?I though i needed to download it? Also, where can I find the instructions for my IDE (Eclipse)?

Comment: Yes I have seen this, but how can I then use it for the Google analytics for my project?

Comment: Include it as a library following the instructions and you can use Google analytics as in first tutorial. Which part you don't understand? I could explain the point you want.

Comment: Im not sure how to add it as a library? I currently have it in eclipse as "import existing android code" but it is not added to my project? Thanks

Comment: Copy the library project at <android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ to the location where you maintain your Android app projects.
Import the library project into your Eclipse workspace. Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.

Comment: In your app project, reference Google Play services library project. See Referencing a Library Project for Eclipse for more information on how to do this.

Comment: Is it a necessary step to refernce the library project? It does not say to do so here in the integration instrcutions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Answer (score 0):

you need to download Google Play services package by Android SDK Manager;

After download, you can find samples in

`<Android SDK path>/extras/google/google_play_services/samples`